# Campaign Member Status update

Tags: process-builder, campaign-member

I have a task which has a custom pick list. Any changes to this field should fire a change in related campaign member status change. I am trying to achieve this through process builder. But I am not able to find the campaign member record at the process builder. Please find the screen shot. [image]

I should be able to find campaign member here !! But I do not get any of it. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Basically, task is not directly linked to `Campaign Member` object.

Task has `WhoId` which can be `Lead` or `Contact` and can be related as `Campaign Member`.

You can either use flow or trigger to find `Campaign Member` record based on `WhoId` and finally update those.